# Maven Tomcat Project Process Simplification

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven, publish

I'm working on a Maven project in Eclipse, where I'm using Maven (`mvn install`) to create my WAR file and run it on my Tomcat server. However, every time I change my application, I have to execute `mvn -o compile war:exploded` and sometimes have to restart Tomcat.

Is there any other way to simplify this long and heavy process?

Answer (score 2):

You may start using:

m2e ( maven to eclipse integration ) -> http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

Eclipse WTP ( web tools platform ) -> http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

WTP will allow you to run Tomcat from eclipse and m2e will take care of converting your Maven build into Eclipse project and integrating it with WTP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `eclipse` then you need not to use `mvn -o compile war:exploded` every time. But yes, you need to use `mvn install` each time you make a change in your application.

This is what you need to do:

- Open `Server View`
- Open expected tomcat server settings. A settings window for tomcat will be opened.
- Select modules tab.
- Choose `Add external web module`. An input form will be opened.
- Browse to your application's `target` (generated by maven) folder and then select already exploded war directory and set it as `Document Base`
- Enter `Path` as the base url for your application.

This is just one time effort.